# Ubuntu 16.04 : How to get display drivers for S3 UniChrome Pro

Tags: 16.04, drivers, display

I have an old PC, with Ubuntu 16.04 installed new (fresh install).
Since it displays only 1280x1024 on a HD display, my first guess goes to display driver issue.

Looking at the MSI website yielded a guess [this is my MSI motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/P4M900M2L/Specification).

How can I get display drivers for Ubuntu? On that site there are only drivers for Windows OS.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: VIA Technologies, Inc. P4M890 [S3 UniChrome Pro] [1106:3343] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P4M890 [S3 UniChrome Pro] [1462:7255]
        Kernel modules: viafb
04:01.0 Audio device [0403]: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller [1106:3288] (rev 10)


$ xrandr -d :0
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     77.00*
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster - lspci is posted in Edit 1.`xrandr` give no real result via `ssh`

Comment: `xrandr` added to question

Comment: @Guy.D Your best bet is to use a discrete graphics card. Any card compatible with PCIe (V.1) will do, even if from 5-7 years ago, just *don't* use that integrated S3 UniChrome Pro.

Comment: So? What should I do with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because S3 does not exist any more and drivers are not available, so the only answer is: "Change your hardware"

Comment: @MichaelBay I think your comments contains the actual answer to this question, although it's not what OP wanted to hear. I'd much rather to posted them as such than close the question as off topic... "you can't" is a valid answer & a good one if an alternative is suggested. Answering this will save the next person wasting their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the problem that my resolution stuck at 640x480 on an old laptop with an `S3 UniChrome Pro` graphics card. After installation of the package `xserver-xorg-video-openchrome` and restarting the system I was able to use the standard resolution of the display (which is 1280x800).

Comment: this old PC was taken down to basement, since it seemed doomed to get solved. Do you think it worked by coinceidence or... ?